# Exporting Multiple AD User's membership via powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to know which group they have membership for. But I want to export `samaccountname` , `displayname` ,`employeeid` like below.

script :

```
$userlist = Get-Content 'C:\your\userlist.txt'

Get-ADUser -Filter '*' -Properties memberof | Where-Object {
  $userlist -contains $_.SamAccountName
} | ForEach-Object {
  $username = $_
  $groups = $_ | Select-Object -Expand memberof |
            ForEach-Object { (Get-ADGroup $_).Name }
  "{0}: {1}" -f $username, ($groups -join ', ')
} | Out-File 'c:\temp\ss.csv'
```

My output :

```
CN=John T,DC=contoso,DC=local: IT_mail_group , IT_mail_group2
```

My desired output :

```
displayname;samaccountname;Staff ID;membership
John T ;johnt;1234; IT_mail_group , IT_mail_group2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 1 object per user, then export using `Export-Csv`:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter '*' -Properties memberof,employeeid,displayname | Where-Object {
  $userlist -contains $_.SamAccountName
} | ForEach-Object {
  [pscustomobject]@{
    DisplayName = $_.DisplayName
    SAMAccountName = $_.SAMAccountName
    EmployeeID = $_.EmployeeID
    Memberships = ($_.memberof |ForEach-Object { (Get-ADGroup $_).Name }) -join ', '
  }
} | Export-Csv -Delimiter ';' -Path 'c:\temp\ss.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I am assuming , missing `displayname` inside properties

Comment: @Arbelac I did indeed